# Selenium xpath count

Tags: java, testing, selenium

I must be overlooking something very obvious. What's wrong with this XPath expression? I want to get a count of table rows which match a regex for `id`?

```
selenium.getXpathCount("//tr[matches(@id,'data-row-\\d+')]");
```

I'm getting:

> com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException:
>   ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]:
>   //tr[matches(@id,'data-row-\d+')]

Here's sample html:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="data-row-0"><td>foo</td></tr>
    <tr id="data-row-1"><td>bar</td></tr>
    <tr id="data-row-2"><td>baz</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selenium 1.x does not support XPath 2.0. Hence you cannot use XPath 2.0 methods like matches(), replace() etc..

You might want to consider XPath 1.0 methods like contains(), starts-with() etc.

Also, to achieve your goal you can try

`//tr[starts-with(@id,'data-row-') and translate(@id,'0123456789','')]`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't know about the difference in versions. `starts-with` did the trick just right. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Try -

```
int tableRowCount = selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='whatever']/tbody/tr").intValue();
```

Comment: The problem is the "whatever" - he needs a pattern match, not a constant.